# What would be the value of y-intercept for the following scenario

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

$-6x < y + a$

In the $xy$ plane if the co-ordinates of the origin do not satisfy the above inequality, which one of the following would be true ?

1. $a > 0$
2. $a < 0$
3. $a \leq 0$
4. $a > 2$
5. $a > 5$

How can I go about this without knowing the slope or the points or even the $y-\text{intercept}$ ?

Comment: if you put the origin you get $a>0$ which is false. So what is the opposite?

Comment: @Vasya A value greater than 0 I suppose, say, 1 ? Or the points (0, 1) or (1, 0) ?

Comment: $a >0$  means $a$ is positive but it's not true, i.e. $a$ is not positive.

Comment: @Vasya So $a$ would be less than 0 ? Or <= 0 ?

Comment: "not positive" means negative or zero

Comment: @Vasya Yeah right. My bad. Thanks for the crisp explanation. +1 for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any pair of coordinates $(x,y)$ that **does not** satisfy the above inequality must satisfy the **negation** of the statement (opposite), i.e., $-6x\ge y+a$. Another way of writing this inequality is $y\le -6x-a$.

If you draw this inequality $y\le -6x-a$ for various values of $a$, you will see that the only possible values for $a$ that will include the origin are when $a\le 0$.

Comment: Yeah right. I got stumped over this and was sat scratching my head through the question. Anyways thanks for the explanation.